# Download a file from a Dropbox Folder Save Into SDcard using Async task in Android Not Working

Tags: android, download, android-asynctask, dropbox

1.I want to **Download a Specific file from Dropbox folder** in Android, then save into **Local SDcard.**

2.I referred DBRoulette Example its Downloading Random Pictures from Dropbox.

also, I tried below code, but not Getting any Solution for download a file.

Please anyone help me.

[Link I referred](http://androidsrc.net/integrating-dropbox-android-apps/)- This Code Download the images randomly.

```
private boolean downloadDropboxFile(String dbPath, File localFile) throws IOException{

    BufferedInputStream br = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bw = null;

    try {
        if (!localFile.exists()) {
            localFile.createNewFile(); //otherwise dropbox client will fail silently
        }

        FileDownload fd = api.getFileStream("dropbox", dbPath, null);
        br = new BufferedInputStream(fd.is);
        bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while (true) {
        read = br.read(buffer);
        if (read <= 0) {
        break;
        }
        bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        //in finally block:
        if (bw != null) {
            bw.close();
        }
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `but not Getting any Solution.` ??? You want to get a file isn it? What do you get instead? Please show how you call downloadDropboxFile(); Looking at BDRoulette example should give you the right code.

Comment: iam getting random picture in DBroutlle Download code not getting Specified file. I want to download a specific file from dropbox then save into Sdcard folder. can you help me @greenapps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following two methods to copy the files under the dropbox directory into a new one.

```
public static final void copyDirectory(File dropboxfile, File newfile) throws IOException {

    newfile.mkdirs();
    File[] files = dropboxfile.listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            copyDirectory(file, new File(newfile, file.getName()));

        } else {
            copyFile(file, new File(newfile, file.getName()));
        }
    }
}


public static final void copyFile(File source, File destination) throws IOException {
    FileChannel sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
    FileChannel targetChannel = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
    sourceChannel.transferTo(0, sourceChannel.size(), targetChannel);
    sourceChannel.close();
    targetChannel.close();
}
```

You can get the dropbox file like following:

```
File dropboxfile = new File(root_to_dropbox_file, file_name);
```

And the new file under the sd card can be created like following:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File newfile = new File(root + "/selected_name");
```

Last but not least add the following permissions into your android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

Comment: Here where i have to get the image file from Dropbox  save into SDCARD

Comment: please edit this code ,i am not able to download the file. please clarify me ,which method is downloading the file then, how to save the download file into SDCard.

Answer (score 1):

The Dropbox Android Core SDK offers two methods for downloading file content. Links to documentation are here:

- [`getFile`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener))
- [`getFileStream`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getFileStream(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

In both, the first parameter is the path in Dropbox to the file you want to download. The DBRoulette sample app picks files randomly, but in real use cases you would supply a specific path, e.g., for a particular file the user selected. For example, you may get information about what files are available using either:

- [`metadata`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#metadata(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String))
- [`delta`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#delta(java.lang.String))

The Dropbox Android Core SDK tutorial also has a small sample here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android#downloading

In that sample code, a file that exists in Dropbox at /magnum-opus.txt is being accessed.

Comment: File file = new File("/magnum-opus.txt");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile("/magnum-opus.txt", null, outputStream, null);
Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The file's rev is: " + info.getMetadata().rev); this Code i am Getting File not Found Exception, please help me .

Comment: Do you have a file in the linked Dropbox at "/magnum-opus.txt"?

Comment: i have tried with differnt file also iam getting file not found exception

Answer (score 0):

> Insert dropboxchooser sdk in your project and use this code. This will open dropbox dialog and see the file list.selected file will download into your phone storage.

```
private DbxChooser mChooser;
private final int DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST = 2020;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mChooser.forResultType(DbxChooser.ResultType.FILE_CONTENT)
            .launch(DropBoxDemo.this, DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST)
    {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            DbxChooser.Result result = new DbxChooser.Result(data);
            Log.d("dropbox", "Link to selected file: " + result.getLink());
            Log.d("dropbox", "Icon to selected file: " + result.getIcon());
            Log.d("dropbox", "Name to selected file: " + result.getName());
            Log.d("dropbox", "Size to selected file: " + result.getSize());
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: i don,t want to choose anything. Just need to send a request to Dropbox Download a file with filename